# Get NetApp disk shelf serial number using 7-mode CLI

Tags: netapp

Is it possible to get the serial number of attached disk shelves from the controller CLI?

I have 3 DS4246's attached to a FAS8020 7-mode HA pair controller. Maybe I'm staring right at it in the `sysconfig -a` or `disk show -v` output?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoop, that was fast. I did find an answer:

Within the `environment status` command output, you can find something like this (listed after fans, batteries, etc):

> Environment for channel 0a
>
> Number of shelves monitored: 3
> Channel: 0a
> Shelf: 1
> vendor identification=NETAPP
> product identification=DS4246
>
> **Product Serial Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX**